# How to catch a map panning | zooming finished event with Android SDK?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, drag, mapactivity

I am looking for a way to receive events when a map **finished** panning or zooming or panning and zooming. Those events are not fired, afaik, from `MapActivity` in the SDK for Android 2.3.3 which I use. I tried the [MapChange](https://github.com/bricolsoftconsulting/MapChange) library, however, it forces you to use `Handler` in your `MapActivity` to ensure to that UI updates are processed on the UI thread; [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508922/356895).

**Question:** Do you know of any support for such events by the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) e.g. by using `FragmentActivity` instead of `MapActivity` - I could not find an alternative solution by now.

Similar questions can be found here:

- [Android MapActivity on map movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620154/android-mapactivity-on-map-movement)
- [How to catch that map panning and zoom are really finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567420/how-to-catch-that-map-panning-and-zoom-are-really-finished)

---

**Edit:**
The MapChange library was [updated some hours ago](https://github.com/bricolsoftconsulting/MapChange/tree/75cf1b2f7f94410939db70b2e6e80b9042f0a608/src/com/bricolsoftconsulting/mapchange). I will check out what has been improved.

---

**Edit:**
The MapChange library has been improved and works much more reliable now and is a good option! Please checkout the GitHub project for further information. However, I leave the question open since I am still interested whether one can do the same with existing components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener) to assign a listener to the changing camera event. Handling that and other events is discussed in the  [Google Maps Android API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#camera_change_events).

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a problem to use a Handler ? You can always post your UI changes to the main thread, why not do that ?

Someone on SO found a way to get a Fragment activity to contain a MapView by changing the support library code but it became too cumbersome for me to use and I reverted to a full-blown Map activity.

Comment: The way Runnables and Handler are used in [MapChange](https://github.com/bricolsoftconsulting/MapChange/tree/3637b8f4f6a97a08ce30a029ee44095aed5e9519/src/com/bricolsoftconsulting/mapchange) appear to me a bit overhead. I wonder how other projects receive such events.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this

```
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener {
                //Do your thing
            }
```

called when camera movement has ended